# How to make ComponentDidMount in component wait for some data?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a website with API calls. In my App.js, in ComponentDidMount() I am making a request for token. After that, I use that token on HomePage and other pages to get data from server for them (like categories, lists, navigation...) and I do it in ComponentDidMount() in those certain components. Now is there a way to make those components wait for token and then fire requests with it, since I am getting tons of errors? Or should I do those calls after I get token all in my App.js and then send data to other components that are called in App?

Comment: make token api call in root component then pass authentication to across component where ever needed.

Comment: how about using `ComponentDidUpdate`?

Comment: @VahidAkhtar's solution would make much cleaner code.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I don't understand, how is that done?

Comment: @LotusFlower can you share your code in sandbox so that i could modify that with your requirement.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I am making a request in App - ComponentDidMount and putting that token in store. Then in other components, let's say Homepage, again in ComponentDidMount I use this.props.token in request for other things (navigation, images) but I get errors.

Comment: Does someone have some good tutorial on how passing authentication is done in case of APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the token you are talking about is the one we get when we login to the site, and before you login your other components should not be accessible, I would recommend when you do login you store that token in browser's storage and once that is done you land to your landing page, then for further calls you can read that token from the storage

Hope it helps you starting,

Comment: It is base token, not login token. I need it for other things on my site. Let's say: fetch(http://something.get-navigation?token=...)

Answer (score 0):

For application tokens I recommend using promises. Personally I use axios to do the job. This could probably be done better, but just for the sake of a fast example:

```
const example = return axios.post('url', logintoken);
example.then(res => {
    axios.post('2ndUrl', res.data.apptoken).then(response => {
        // Do something here
    });
});
```